# How to solve for parameter of rotations

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, rotations

Given unit vectors $a$ and $b$, I want to find a rotation $R$ such that:

$$
b = Ra
$$

and

$$
R = R_y(\phi)R_x(\theta)
$$

where $R_x(\theta)$ is a right-handed rotation around the X axis by an angle of $\theta$ and $R_y(\phi)$ is the same for Y, for some $\phi$ and $\theta$.

I don't particularly want the actual angles, I just want to make sure that $R$ is a product of these two rotations. I approached this problem by looking at the matrix representation of $R$ and solving for the angles, but it seems inelegant. Is there a more direct way, perhaps using quaternions?

Here's the approach I have now:

If I expand R, I get:

$$
b =
\begin{bmatrix}
cos(\phi) & sin(\phi) sin(\theta) & sin(\phi) cos(\theta)\\
0 & cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta)\\
-sin(\phi) & sin(\theta) cos(\phi) & cos(\phi) cos(\theta)\\
\end{bmatrix}
a
$$

Using the harmonic addition theorem,

$$
x \cdot cos(\phi)+y \cdot sin(\phi) = c \cdot cos(\phi + \lambda) = z\\
c = sgn(x) \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\\
\lambda = \operatorname{arctan} \left(- \frac{y}{x} \right)\\
\phi = \pm \operatorname{arccos} \left(\frac{z}{c} \right) - \lambda
$$

I can solve the second row for $\theta$. This has two solutions, and I want the one where $| \theta |  < \pi / 2$. Knowing this, I can again use the harmonic addition theorem to solve the first row for $\phi$. This again produces two solutions, and I pick the one that produces the correct $b_3$. This works, but the biggest problem is that solving the harmonic additions is undefined in several places ($a_2 = 0$, $b_2 > c$, $b_1 > c$). Is there a better way?

Comment: A general rotation has 3 degrees of freedom.  Is there some special constraint in place such that your rotation i s constrained in such a way?  The axis of rotation is $a\times b$.  The angle is $\cos^{-1} (a\cdot b)$.  There are formulas to get to Euler angles from there.

Comment: @Tpofofn: I want to find the rotation of an "FPS-style" camera that has these two degrees of freedom. Finding an arbitrary rotation is not a problem.

Comment: I think your answer is at  
http://lolengine.net/blog/2013/09/18/beautiful-maths-quaternion-from-vectors

Comment: @dcromley I think that finds _a_ rotation but not the one I want, which can be reached by rotating around X, then Y.